# How to access outermost forloop.counter with nested for loops in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible to access the forloop.counter for the outermost for loop in the following template in Django:

```
{% for outerItem in outerItems %}
    {% for item in items%}
        <div>{{ forloop.counter }}.&nbsp;{{ item }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

forloop.counter returns the innermost for loop's counter in the above example

Answer (score 288, accepted):

You can use `forloop.parentloop` to get to the outer `forloop`, so in your case `{{forloop.parentloop.counter}}`.

Comment: What if I have more than two loops and I want to access certain loop? Should I use
"parentloop"."parentloop" to gradully appoarch it?
It sounds inefficient.

Answer (score 26):

you can also use [**with**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

Caches a complex variable under a simpler name. This is useful when accessing an “expensive” method (e.g., one that hits the database) multiple times.

```
{% for outerItem in outerItems %}
  {% with forloop.counter as outer_counter %}
    {% for item in items%}
        <div>{{ outer_counter }}.&nbsp;{{ item }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

if using high version of Django
you could use

```
{% with outer_counter=forloop.counter %}
```

Note: With doesn't allow spaces before or after `=`

I've checked, Django 1.4.x - Django 1.9.x support the two methods.

this is more clear when have many for loops

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the `forloop.parentloop` is not enough.

Check out [django-templateaddons3](https://pypi.org/project/django-templateaddons3/) and its [{% counter %}](https://django-templateaddons3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/template_tags/counter.html) tag for a full-fledged solution.