# django addition

Tags: django, django-templates

how to increment value of a variable in a template..??

```
{% for s in list%}
     {% for subject in s%}
             {% for sub in subject %}

                    <div id="{{ sub| getid:i }}"></div> 
                    # here i want to increment the value of i 
             {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: if you know how to increment the value of a variable in a template, then plz let me know..!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to increase `i` over all nested loops, you can pass another stateful context variable, such as `i=itertools.count()`, and in the template, you use

```
<div id="{{ sub| getid:i.next }}"></div>
```

The [Django documentation on the template language design](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) states the philosophy of the template language is that

> the template system is meant to express presentation, not program logic.

And this often means you cannot manipulate state directly with filters. To achieve state changes, you will have to create your own stateful variables whose state can be altered via a function call.

Answer (score 3):

Using a template for loop? You may try this using:

> forloop.counter

see the docs here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs

Implementation:

```
{% for s in list%} 
  {% for subject in s%} 
    {% for sub in subject %}
                <div id="{{ sub| getid:forloop.counter+(forloop.parentloop.counter - 1)*total_iterations_inner_loop+(forloop.parentloop.parentloop.counter-1)*total_iterations_mid_loop*total_iterations_inner_loop }}"></div> 
         {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But wen the second for loop runs again, then i would again get the same values in the third for loop.

Comment: hmm...looking into use of nested forloop counter.

Comment: In the getid argument pass the sum of the forloop counters as in the answer update.

Comment: this wont work becouse , suppose the second for loop is running for the second time, then your expression will return 0+1+0 , and this is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

check out http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add

Comment: this would only return the addition of the values but wouldn't change the variable's value..!!

Comment: This will only change the output. It won't change the value of variable `i`.

Comment: you may try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376511/how-to-access-outermost-forloop-counter-with-nested-for-loops-in-django-templates for accessing the parent loop counter and use the add tag to update the innermost loop according to outer ones.

Comment: what i want is, every time 
<div id="{{ sub| getid:i }}"></div> is encountered , then i should have new value, starting from 0 , 1 , 2 and so on...