# Reading a list inside a tuple in Django

Tags: django

My problem is that I want to read a list (with a for loop) which is inside a tuple like this:

```
items = {a, b, [1, 2, 3]}
```

'a' and 'b' are other data I need.

Now for reading a list I do this, which doesn't work:

```
{% for item in items.3 %}
  {{item}}
{% endfor %}
```

So my question is how can I read, with a for loop, a list which is inside a tuple?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I deleted the erlang tag, because there are no references to Erlang programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted the part of code and started over.
An extra tip: If the list in the tuple is a list of tuples and you want to read a part of the tuple. You have to use a new for loop to read it.

For example, I have this:

```
items = {a, b, [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]}
```

Now for getting a list out of a tuple:

```
{% for item in items.3 %}
    {{item}}
{% endfor %}
```

Now for getting something out of the tuple from the list

I try to do this but it doesn't work, if there are people who know how to fix this, please add a comment:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{item.1}}
{% endfor %}
```

This is my trick to get it done:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% for i in item %}
        {{i}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

To get the counter of the outer most loop check this post:
[how-to-access-outermost-forloop-counter-with-nested-for-loops-in-django-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376511/how-to-access-outermost-forloop-counter-with-nested-for-loops-in-django-template)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Python indexes in lists/tuples are started from zero.  So you should use the index `2`:

```
{% for item in items.2 %}
  {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

BTW, tuples are defined with round brackets, not the curly:

```
items = (a, b, [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: It didn't work. If I type {{items.0}}, I get errors. 
I get curly brackets even in django. I think because I work with Erlang in the underlaying code.

Comment: Curly brackets in python is a shortcut for define a `set`.  Python sets are not indexed, so `{1, 2, 3}[0]` will raise the error.  And of course a tuple `(1, 2, 3)[0]` will work fine.

Comment: I cracked the case. But I don't know what the problem was. I deleted everything of that part of code and started over. Now it just works fine.
Thanks for the help any way.