# How can I use the forloop.counter0 as a key in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

I use a custom Widget to modify the context for the widget template (add more information).

Context:

```
'selected': [[3, 9], [3, 4, 7, 6]], 'depth_levels': {0: [{'name': 'Category A', 'value': 3, 'depth': 0, 'parent_id': None, 'children': [4, 9]}, {'name': 'Category B', 'value': 8, 'depth': 0, 'parent_id': None, 'children': []}], 1: [{'name': 'Category A_1', 'value': 4, 'depth': 1, 'parent_id': 3, 'children': [5, 7]}

{% for path in widget.selected %}
        {% for selected in path %}

            {% for level in widget.depth_levels.forloop.counter0 %}
                {{ level }}

            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

First I cycle thru the selected(path) and the internal arrays(selected).
I want to use the {{forloop.counter0}} as a key for depth_levels.

The issue: `{{widget.depth_levels.forloop.counter0}}` doesn't return anything.

The forloop.counter is not used as index for a list, but it is used as key to a dictionary.

Using '.' to access is the default way in which Django templates access a dictionary*  Using  '0', '1' - `{{widget.depth_levels.0}}`- etc instead of `forloop.counter0` it works.

Using a custom template tag again has an issue because the access is inside a `for` and can't use `{{}}` inside:

```
{% for level in widget.depth_levels.forloop.counter0 %}
```

*The keys that I need to access depth_levels are from 0 to the length of each array inside the `selected`, the 'path' array in the example.*

The values in selected arrays tell me later where to add attributes are not related to the keys of depth_levels.

My end goal is to access the `name`, `value` in the dictionaries that are in the array.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376511/how-to-access-outermost-forloop-counter-with-nested-for-loops-in-django-template) might help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference list item by index within Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651172/reference-list-item-by-index-within-django-template)

Comment: ^see the second answer

Comment: @Laur Ivan - my situation is different I don't need to access {{forloop.counter}} as default or his parent (I can do that no issues here) but to use it like a key for a dictionary

Comment: @Sayse The forloop.counter is not used as index for a list, but it is used as key to a dictionary(as in the other post). Using '.' to access is the default way in which Django templates access a dictionary, this is why I don't understand why it doesn't work. If I use '0', '1', not 'dynamic' it works

Comment: Why can't you use something like this:
`{% for key, level in widget.depth_levels.items %}`?

Comment: @Sayse - I checked the questions and answers and the situation is different, acces different structured , used inside {% for %} in my case, not outside, so is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Piyush Das I need to access specific keys not all, If you take a look at selected, you see that the lists inside have different length. Depending on the length of the list I know how many and which keys I access (this is why I need the foorloop.counter0

Comment: Dictionary or list doesn't matter, its the same syntax and the same answer of make a custom template tag

Comment: @Sayse - I understand that, I added more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a filter like this (To know more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters):

```
@register.filter
def value_by_key(d, key):    
    return d[key]
```

Then use it like this:

```
% for path in widget.selected %}
    {% for level in widget.depth_levels|value_by_key:path|length %}
        {{ level }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The keys that I need are from 0 to the length of the each array inside the path, so the selected is not the key, this is why I need the {{forloop.counter}}. Compared to your example I also go one level deeper.

Comment: So you can use "forloop.counter" instead of "selected" (without inverted quotation)

Answer (score 0):

If your end goal is to access each name, value in the dictionaries that are in the array, then you should do something like this.

```
{% for path in widget.selected %}
    {% for selected in path %}
        {% for key, level in widget.depth_levels.items %}
            {% for key_obj in level %}
                {{ key_obj.name }}
                {{ key_obj.value }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The keys that I need are from 0 to the length of the each array inside the path, so the selected is not the key, this is why I need the {{forloop.counter}}. The goal is to access names based on arrays in selected length, not necessary all of them.

Comment: Provide a sample output of what you want. It is very unclear from your question as to what you want.