# Total number of iterations for Django nested loops

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

Example: [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

```
cities = [
    {'name': 'Mumbai', 'population': '19,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
    {'name': 'New York', 'population': '20,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
    {'name': 'Calcutta', 'population': '15,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
    {'name': 'Chicago', 'population': '7,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
    {'name': 'Tokyo', 'population': '33,000,000', 'country': 'Japan'},
]

{% regroup cities by country as country_list %}

{% for country, local_cities in country_list %}
    {% for city in local_cities %}
       {{total_number_of_iteration_till_now}} {{ city.name }}: {{ city.population }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**How do I get the total iteration number of both inner and outer for loop for each iteration?**

Desired output:

```
India
1)Mumbai: 19,000,000
USA
2)New York: 20,000,000
India
3)Calcutta: 15,000,000
USA
4)Chicago: 7,000,000
Japan
5)Tokyo: 33,000,000
```

`forloop.counter` and `forloop.counter0` return only inner index

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access outermost forloop.counter with nested for loops in Django templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376511/how-to-access-outermost-forloop-counter-with-nested-for-loops-in-django-template)

Comment: What's the goal you're aiming at? Maybe there's a better way how to achieve that...

Comment: Im aiming at getting the total number of iteration for each iteration to visualise it together with each city(in this case)

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74094611

Answer (score 1):

You can use ordered list (`<ol>`) and skip the items which shouldnt be numbered

```
<ol>
{% for country, local_cities in country_list %}
    {# this one wont be numbered #}
    <li style="list-style-type: none">{{ country }}</li>
        {% for city in local_cities %}
          <li>{{ city.name }}: {{ city.population }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Comment: Then add the index in Python already, doing this kind of this logic does not belong into template.